# How to read a value in text file in batch

Tags: batch-file, text-files

[image]

So I need use the GPU temperature as a variable in batch but I haven't quite understood how to pick only it, nothing else. I need the the latest temperature every 10 seconds. How to pick always the latest temperature from the text file and set it as %temperature%

Comment: The think that you've provided doesn't seem to work. Could you please post the content of the file inside a code block and add it to the bottom of your original post? If the text file is too large, trim it down so only the most relevant information remains.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:loop
for /f "tokens=3 delims=, " %%a in (input.txt) do set "temperature=%%a"
echo %temperature%
timeout /t 10 >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: If the file is read when the last written line is unfortunate enough to read, `     Date           , GPU Temperature [°C] ,` the output would read, `Temperature`. Perhaps using `FindStr` to ignore lines beginning with a space would be useful: `For /F Tokens^=4 %%A In ('FindStr/BLVC:" " input.txt') Do Set "temperature=%%A"`

Comment: Personally, I'd use `%%a in (' findstr /L "." "input.txt" ')` to filter-out the lines not containing `.` as a literal character. (note to OP: single-quotes around the `findstr` command - double around the strings)